# Wordpress plugin options page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a wordpress twitter plugin, for my options page I need to save the form into the table I've managed to create. I've created the form, now I need to know how to make sure it posts into my table? I have the following code and my table name is wp_twitter_carla.

```
function register_mysettings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'twitter-settings-group', 'twitteruser' );
    register_setting( 'twitter-settings-group', 'notweets' );
    register_setting( 'twitter-settings-group', 'replies' );
    register_setting( 'twitter-settings-group', 'retweets' );
}

function twitter_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Twitter Feed by Carla</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'twitter-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'twitter-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Twitter Username</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="twitteruser" value="<?php echo get_option('twitteruser'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Number of tweets to show</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="notweets" value="<?php echo get_option('notweets'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Show replies?</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="replies" value="<?php echo get_option('replies'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Show retweets?</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="retweets" value="<?php echo get_option('retweets'); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: When you register a setting, it goes to the table `wp_options`. You don't need your own table to save only this 4 options... I think you intention is to save the actual tweets in your table, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress should save your settings in wp_options table. Open phpmyadmin, choose you database and click 
sql write there this sql code

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE '%twitter-settings-group%' OR `option_value` LIKE '%twitter-settings-group%
```

There should be one result wp is serializing your form and keeping in one row in database.

Best Regards,
Davit.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer your specific question directly, I'd recommend that you use the [Redux Framework](http://reduxframework.com/).  It's an options framework built on the WordPress Settings API and it's extremely easy to use.  It'll handle all of the database posting, retrieving, etc for you.  It's definitely worth taking some time to learn their API, I think you'd be happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

When your are using `register_settings();`, wordpress is storing these settings in the `wp_options` table. See the [Options-API Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/) for a full example.

You can change the HTML for displaing the settings, so Wordpress is handling it for you:

```
<form action="options.php" method="post">
    <?php
        // output security fields for the registered setting "wporg"
        settings_fields( 'wporg' );
        // output setting sections and their fields
        // (sections are registered for "wporg", each field is registered to a specific section)
        do_settings_sections( 'wporg' );
        // output save settings button
       submit_button( 'Save Settings' );
    ?>
</form>
```

WordPress is automatically receiving the values and storing it in the options-table. You also can add a validation-callback to check and sanitize the values.